# How to work with complex numbers in C language?

Tags: c, complex-numbers

I need to do complex numbers operation. After I defined a variable, named 'squareRoot', using "complex.h" stadard library, however, Visual Studio 2022 told me identifier 'squareRoot' is undefined. It made me comfused! What's wrong with my code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NwkF.png)

I just want to know how to define a complex variable, even though I have referenced some similar codes that define that complex number.

Comment: All code and error messages should be posted directly in the question as text, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: I don't think the Microsoft C compiler supports standard C complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine as far as C is concerned, but Microsoft has always been a bit out of step with C standards. It seems that the functions from `complex.h` are supported in VS2022, but you will have to use `_Dcomplex` in place of `double complex`. You can read more about [support for `complex.h` in Visual Studio 2022 here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=msvc-170)

Comment: After 40+ years of professional C programming I can confirm that it is commonly an error to program C with a Microsoft compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The link you gave me is also helpful.